# Elasticsearch summing buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, buckets

I have the following request which will return the count of all documents with a status of either "Accepted","Released" or closed.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "slices": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "status.raw",
        "include": {
          "pattern": "Accepted|Released|Closed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my case the response is:

```
 "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Closed",
          "doc_count": 2216
        },
        {
          "key": "Accepted",
          "doc_count": 8
        },
        {
          "key": "Released",
          "doc_count": 6
        }
      ]
```

Now I'd like to add all of them up into a single field.
I tried using pipeline aggregations and even tried the following sum_bucket (which apparently only works on multi-bucket):

```
"total":{
    "sum_bucket":{
        "buckets_path": "slices"
    }
}
```

Anyone able to help me out with this?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but why not simply querying on `status.raw:(Accepted OR Released OR Closed)` and then simply checking the total hits?

Comment: I need the buckets separate as well.

I need the following:
closed,accepted,released,total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is to use the [`filters` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html) instead and define all the buckets you need, like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "slices": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "accepted": {
            "term": {
              "status.raw": "Accepted"
            }
          },
          "released": {
            "term": {
              "status.raw": "Released"
            }
          },
          "closed": {
            "term": {
              "status.raw": "Closed"
            }
          },
          "total": {
            "terms": {
              "status.raw": [
                "Accepted",
                "Released",
                "Closed"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a viable answer as well, I'll keep this in mind and see which works better in the long run! Thank you!

Comment: I have no stats to back this up, but this version should be more efficient than the one with pattern inclusion which has to run on all different `status.raw` terms. It will probably depend on how many different terms you have. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Mmmmm, I hadn't thought of the speed aspect but logic dictates that you're right. Do you perhaps know how to divide by terms as well? I have some unsolved es related questions still open so if you'd like to take a look at those too I'd be ever grateful.

Comment: What do you mean by "divide by terms"?

Comment: Take a look if you please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40420880/elasticsearch-bucket-script-and-buckets-paths-return-could-not-find-aggregato/40432271#40432271

ps: thanks for fixing the title, I noticed it too haha

Answer (score 4):

With `sum_bucket` and your already existent aggregation:

```
  "aggs": {
    "slices": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "status.raw",
        "include": {
          "pattern": "Accepted|Released|Closed"
        }
      }
    },
    "sum_total": {
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "slices._count"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I accepted this answer because it's very close to my original query. I just missed ._count on my bucket path :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add count with [value_count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html) sub aggregation and then use [sum_bucket pipeline aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html)

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "unique_status": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "status.raw",
        "include": "Accepted|Released|Closed"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "status.raw"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sum_status": {
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "unique_status>count"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Comment: You can directly use `_count` ;-)

Comment: Oh Yes, Thanks :)